# Why do some API versions in azure devops not work with some organizations?

Tags: api, azure-devops

Is there an option to select API version in Azure Devops, for example - we have a chart for TFS vs the API Version here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 Is there a mapping or some settings in the azure organization where we can find this?

Sample Request -

[https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/{TeamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?&timeframe=true&api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganizationName%7D/%7BProjectName%7D/%7BTeamId%7D/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?&timeframe=true&api-version=6.0)

Reponse would be in the form of - Reponse of this API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: You need to be more specific in your example and provide a reproducable example of your problem that illustrates **exactly what you are trying to do** and **what the actual output is**. At the moment it is not clear neither what is not working nor what you have tried.  Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Azure DevOps Services support all previous API-versions** out of the box, the self hosted version (Azure DevOps server) support all previous versions up to some point in time. For a complete list of what versions are supported where, please see the documentation on [supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops#supported-versions)

When making a call to the REST API the caller can [specify which REST API version the call targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops#usage) in one of the following ways

1. Through a HTTP request header:

   ```
   Accept: application/json;api-version=6.0
   ```
2. Through a Query parameter:

   ```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/{area}/{resource}?api-version=6.0
   ```

Comment: Yes, that's true but I can't find the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 to be working for some organizations, I've changed the versions - but it's now showing up @danielorn

Comment: Okay, can you please update your question with an example, complete with the request you are sending, the response you receieve and what your expectations were

Comment: Updated, with the request and response, @danielorn